# Is it possible to install SQL Server on Windows 11 running on Parallels on Mac M2 chip?

Tags: apple-m1, windows-11, parallels, sql-server-2019-express

I have a brand-new Mac laptop with an Apple M2 chip. I have installed Parallels and installed Windows 11 under parallels.

I have made a few attempts to install SQL Server 2019 Express on this Windows 11 OS, but every attempt have failed. Is it possible to have a copy of SQL Server (of any version) installed on a Windows 11 OS which is running on top of Apple M2 chip?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm working on the same issue, but with an M1 processor...

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install SQL server on Mac M1 Pro or UTM-Windows 11 virtual machine on Mac M1 Pro by following steps

1. Download zip file containing install2022Developer.bat and install2022Developer.ps1 files from this link in your system https://github.com/jimm98y/MSSQLEXPRESS-M1-Install
2. Run the install2022Developer.bat using Terminal - CMD or Powershell

how to run bat files refer this link
https://www.wikihow.com/Run-a-Batch-File-from-the-Command-Line-on-Windows

3. Download and install Microsoft SQL Server management studio (SSMS) and install manually, if it is not installed directly via step-2 using following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16

4. You can also install SSDT tools accordingly if required

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 14):

It is possible to install and run SQL Server Express 2019 and 2022 on the Apple M1 chip, but it is not officially supported. Fortunately, the root cause of the issue is not in the SQL Server itself, but in the installation. I've created a script which will install SQL Server Express on Windows 11 in a Parallels VM on Apple M1. You can find it here [MSSQLEXPRESS-M1-Install](https://github.com/jimm98y/MSSQLEXPRESS-M1-Install).

Comment: Thanks! I did installed it using your script. One question: how to enable and connect using the "sa" account?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server Express 2014 [Download SQL Express 2014 here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42299)
[image: Download the SQL Server Express 2014 and the MGMT Studio (SSIS/SSMS) tools]
download the 32 bit (x86) and use the defaults for installation process with one exception

** USE MIXED MODE and enter an SA password **

[image: Installation complete!]

When you run the second file (SQL ServerManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe) it will open [image: the same option list]. select the first option and Select modify/upgrade the SQL Express instance that you just added. Add all the DB Management tools in the next screen. Both pieces of the install will take some time, so don't give up on it even if it seems to be hung.

[image: Here are the tools to be added.]

When you open SQL Server Management Studio, you may get this... I'm not sure what to do with this, but if you have suggestions, please add in comments.

[image: Notice on opening SSMS] It did not prevent me from being able to login and create a database.

Comment: How do you run an .exe file, build for intel x86 on Mac M2 silicon chip under MacOS?